# Unchecking checkbox does not undo command?

Tags: java, checkbox

Its my first time programming checkboxes; I figured out how to make a checkbox appear, and do a command when checked. However,  when the box is unchecked, instead of undoing the command, it instead does the command a second time. How can I undo the command when unchecking the box?

Code: (instantiation of checkboxes)

```
    negA    = new JCheckBox("Neg");
    negA.addActionListener(this);
    negA.setActionCommand("A-5");

    tossupA = new JCheckBox("Tossup");
    tossupA.addActionListener(this);
    tossupA.setActionCommand("A10");

    powerA  = new JCheckBox("Power");
    powerA.addActionListener(this);
    powerA.setActionCommand("A05");
```

Command:

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
    //get the String value from the button pressed
    String result = e.getActionCommand();
    char team = result.charAt(0);

    //set text on screen to reflect new score
    String screenText = "Team "+(team)+"'s total score for this tossup: ";

    //add score to subtotal and show on screentext
    if(team=='A'){
        teamATempScore += Integer.parseInt(result.substring(1));
        screenText += teamATempScore;
    }
    //and now for B
    else if(team=='B'){
        teamBTempScore += Integer.parseInt(result.substring(1));
        screenText += teamBTempScore;
    }
```

When the box is unchecked, I want the score to decrement by the amount that it was incremented, but instead the score just increments again :(

Thanks!

(yes, if you were wondering, this is a scorekeeping program for a game of Quizbowl) :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The listener just checks to see if the checkBox was clicked -- It doesn't check if it went from unchecked to checked, or vice versa.

Use the .isSelected() method to determine whether the checkbox is checked or not after it becomes clicked.

For example:

```
 if (negA.isSelected()) 
 {
      //the checkbox was checked after they clicked it, do something
 }
 else 
 {
      //the checkbox was unchecked after they clicked it, do something else
 }
```

Comment: Ok, thanks! But would this cause the 'else' to run whenever the checkbox is ignored? For example, it would increment the score by -5 (decrement by 5) when checked, and decrement by -5 when unchecked after being checked, but would it still decrement by -5 if just unchecked from the beginning?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question fully.  If the check box is ignored, it means the user never clicked it.  Since they never clicked it, the actionListener won't hear it, and won't execute the part of your code that changes the score.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. I thought you meant to put it somewhere else. Problem solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the state of the control and then either increment or decrement. The compiler cannot auto generate the reverse of your code.

To check the state of the checkbox, you call the isSelected() method on it like in the example below.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class CheckboxExample extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private javax.swing.JCheckBox jCheckBox1;

    public CheckboxExample() {
        jCheckBox1 = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new java.awt.FlowLayout());

        jCheckBox1.setText("CheckMe");
        jCheckBox1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jCheckBox1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(jCheckBox1);

        pack();
    }

    // this will get called when the state of the checkbox changes
    private void jCheckBox1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        if(jCheckBox1.isSelected()) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Checked", "Message", 
                                          JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
        else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Unchecked", "Message", 
                                          JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE); 
        }            
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new CheckboxExample().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm a noob. What does that mean? I thought checkboxes were boolean values? How do I check a state?

Comment: Example added for you @Nyaxoffon